# Why not have setState be asynchronous in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So... when I do something like:

```js
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

// in something else now
setCount(5);
```

Now, I don't really know when `setCount` is going to update... I can't be sure. Obviously, the current solution is

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    // ... then do something
}, [count]);
```

but why not make `setCount` async?

```js
// count might not be 5, but will definitely have updated.
setCount(5).then(count => {
    // ... then do something
})
```

This is a question about React's hook's API design. I am not asking about *how* I can achieve something, more *why* the library is built this way.

Comment: What would be the use case for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is fundamentally designed around writing *declarative* code, instead of *imperative* code.

It's not about time, it's about dependencies.

You are not supposed to ask *"when `setCount` is going to update"*, you should not even think about code like *"do this, and then do something else"*, you should only think about *"the state should be this value now"*, and *"state B depends on state A"*.

I.e. your example

```
setCount(5).then( count => { /* ...do something else */ } )
```

says *"as soon as this value is set, do something else..."*.

That is *imperative* code, and thus violates the basic concepts of React (i.e. writing declarative code).

#### declare:

Instead you should *declare* what you want the state to be *now*.
E.g. you should say *"The variable `count` should be `5`"*:

```
setCount(5);
```

#### dependencies:

And then you specify dependencies, e.g. you might say somewhere else in your code *"`count` items of my data should be displayed"*, so the `items` array depends on `count`, e.g.:

```
const displayedItems = React.useMemo(
    () => data.filter( (_, index) => index < count ),
    [ count, data ]
);
```

#### side effects:

If e.g. not enough data is available, you might use a *side effect*, aka. `useEffect`, that depends on `count` and the available data, and might fetch some additional data, e.g.:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        if( data.length < count ){
            fetchMoreData( count ).then( newData => {
                setData( newData );
            });
        }
    },
    [ count, data ]
);
```

#### Links

- [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) / [State as a snapshot](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/adding-interactivity#state-as-a-snapshot)
- [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) / [synchronizing-with-effects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects)
- [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)

Answer (score 1):

That is a good look in, to the design. Well there are some reason why `setState` is not `asynchronous`. Based on my experience and perspective, it is mainly the performance optimization factor why the `setState` is `not asynchronous` in React.

To understand this further lets say, when you call `setState` in React, the component is scheduled for a `re-render` but is not executed right away. Instead, it does the `re-render` at the conclusion of the cycle after batching all state modifications that take place within a single render cycle.

Now if the `setState` were `asynchronous`, Each state change would start a new re-render cycle, which would be less effective. SetState may be made synchronous so that React can group together many state modifications and only need to re-render the component once.

Ultimately, React's design choice to make `setState` `synchronous` is a compromise between efficiency and complexity, and it has been successful in helping React components manage state.

Answer (score 1):

setState is actually not async in reality because an async function is expected to return a promise. But It does appear as async, because of something called batching of states i.e. The way in which react actually updates the state. If you want to understand it even deeply... learn about batching of states in react.